# how can I put a macron over the letter "m" in MS Word?

Tags: keyboard

I'm running MS Word 16.16.5 on macOS Mojave 10.14.1. I can't figure out how to put a macron over the letter "m". I can create with vowels but not consonants with the ABC-Extended.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Type <kbd>m</kbd> and then <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>.  You may need to change the font to get it to look good.

Comment: That simple! Thank you. It works with other fonts. Going to test out those that are closest to Times New Roman.